# Trouble with T-SQL joins on multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have the following code

```
DECLARE @instance TABLE
                  (
                      instance_name VARCHAR(40), 
                      b VARCHAR(40), 
                      c VARCHAR(40)
                  )

INSERT INTO @instance
VALUES 
('inst1', 'a', 'a'),
('inst2', 'a', 'b'),
('inst3', 'a', 'c')

DECLARE @db TABLE
            (
                [database_name] VARCHAR(40), 
                instance_name VARCHAR(40), 
                f VARCHAR(40)
            )

INSERT INTO @db
VALUES 
('db1', 'inst1', 'a'),
('db2', 'inst1', 'b')

DECLARE @override TABLE
                  (
                      name VARCHAR(40), 
                      instance_name VARCHAR(40), 
                      [database_name] VARCHAR(40), 
                      i VARCHAR(40)
                  )

INSERT INTO @override
VALUES 
('inst1.db1', 'inst1', 'db1', 'a'),
('inst1', 'inst1', NULL, 'b')

SELECT
    i.instance_name, d.database_name, s.i  
FROM
    @instance i
JOIN
    @db d ON i.instance_name = d.instance_name
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    @override s ON d.instance_name + '.' + d.database_name = s.name 
                   OR (d.instance_name = s.name AND s.database_name IS NULL)
```

However the output results in

| Instance_name | database_name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| inst1 | db1 | a |
| inst1 | db1 | b |
| inst1 | db2 | b |

The value of inst1.db1 should be a but the results show both a and b.

I believe this to be a join issue.

Can anyone please provide guidance?

Comment: Are you using Azure sql?

Comment: No, the result is correct. Are you sure you initialized @override correctly, or gave the correct parameters to the join with override? Maybe you meant **d**.database_name is null, or for both d and s 's .database_names to be null, or maybe even d.f = s.i ??

Comment: d.database name will never be null. I have an over ride table for contacts however there can be a contact on an instance and all DBs on that instance will be that contact name. However if a specific database on that instance has an over ride than I need the contact to be listed.

Comment: It is not being run on Azure SQL.

Comment: Regardless, the join between `d` and `s` over `d.instance_name = s.name AND s.database_name IS NULL` will produce a result row with `inst1, db1, b`. The `('inst1', 'inst1', NULL, 'b')` row of `@override` simply matches with the `('db1', 'inst1', 'a')` row of `@db`.

Comment: What is the confusion? It's joining based your `or` condition, the full join gets you all join combinations and the condition allows for both a and b.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to define overrides for both instance+database and instance-only, but want an instance+database match to supersede an instance-only match, you will need additional logic.

Two options come to mind:

1. Define two joins and use `COALESCE()` to select the preferred match.
2. Use an `OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1...ORDER BY)` to pick the match of higher priority.

Something like:

```
select i.instance_name, d.database_name, coalesce(s1.i, s2.i) as Value
from @instance i
join @db d on i.instance_name = d.instance_name
left join @override s1 on
    d.instance_name + '.' + d.database_name = s1.name
left join @override s2 on
    d.instance_name = s2.name and s2.database_name IS NULL
```

or

```
select i.instance_name, d.database_name, s.i as Value
from @instance i
join @db d on i.instance_name = d.instance_name
outer apply (
    select top 1 s.*
    from @override s
    where d.instance_name + '.' + d.database_name = s.name 
        or (d.instance_name = s.name AND s.database_name IS NULL)
    order by case when s.database_name is not null then 1 else 2 end
) s
```

(Formatting in style of original post, before it was mass-reformatted.)

Results:

| instance_name | database_name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| inst1 | db1 | a |
| inst1 | db2 | b |

The second unwanted inst1.db1 result has been eliminated. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/31TvdDrB) for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing is related to the join condition in your query. The problem lies in the last part of the `FULL OUTER JOIN` condition where you're joining `d.instance_name` with `s.name` and checking if `s.database_name` is `NULL`. This condition is causing the undesired result.

To fix the issue and get the expected output, you can modify the join condition as follows:

```
DECLARE @instance TABLE(instance_name VARCHAR(40), b VARCHAR(40) , c VARCHAR(40))

INSERT INTO @instance
VALUES 
('inst1','a','a') ,
('inst2','a','b') ,
('inst3','a','c')

DECLARE @db TABLE([database_name] VARCHAR(40), instance_name VARCHAR(40) , f VARCHAR(40))

INSERT INTO @db
VALUES 
('db1','inst1','a'),
('db2','inst1','b')

DECLARE @override TABLE(name VARCHAR(40), instance_name VARCHAR(40), [database_name] VARCHAR(40) , i VARCHAR(40))

insert into @override
values
('inst1.db1', 'inst1','db1','a'),
('inst1', 'inst1',null,'b')
SELECT 
    instance_name, database_name, Value
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        i.instance_name, d.database_name, COALESCE(o.i, d.f) AS Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.instance_name, d.database_name ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM 
        @instance i
    JOIN 
        @db d ON i.instance_name = d.instance_name
    LEFT JOIN 
        @override o ON (d.instance_name = o.instance_name AND d.database_name = o.database_name)
                     OR (o.instance_name = d.instance_name AND o.database_name IS NULL)
    ) AS sub
WHERE 
    rn = 1
```

| instance_name | database_name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| inst1 | db1 | a |
| inst1 | db2 | b |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IXuHzoFr)

Comment: Be aware that with no well-defined order (`ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`), the `ROW_NUMBER()` function can assign values arbitrarily, and the inst1/db1/b result might also be produced. This can be demonstrated by swapping the order of inserts into the @override table as shown [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wypgu3fx). If order matters, an unambiguous ORDER BY must always be defined. The tendency of small unordered datasets to return data in an order related to the order of insert should not be misinterpreted as expected or well-defined behavior. Such behaviors will change with database size and age.